# NullPointerException when transferring variable between classes

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

[`MainActivity.java`](http://pastebin.com/DxhgeRY9)

Now I'm trying to transfer a String from a Class to another, in this way:

```
//setting it public
public String grid_columns;

sp = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);

//getting the String from a shared preference file
//ignore that its a number, in the file its considering a string
        this.grid_columns = sp.getString("grid_columns", "3");
        Log.i("TAG",grid_columns);
        //menes.setGrid_columns(grid_columns);
```

Now in the other class, I need to get this string and Log it just to test.
AdapterListView.java
http://pastebin.com/NxfHjXjv

```
//getting the String from the other activity
MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
        String grid_columnsA = main.grid_columns;

        if(convertView == null){

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);
            Log.i("TAG",grid_columnsA);
//NullPointerException in this line (Log.i...)
```

What am I doing wrong?
I already tried getters and setters and NullPointerException again.

Comment: is `this.grid_columns = sp.getString("grid_columns", "3");` getting called in `MainActivity` constructor?  Also are you sure that `sp.getString("grid_columns", "3");` doesn't return null.

Comment: Also the code you posted is a mess and incomplete. it is hard to know what your real code is doing as you haven't shown how things are being called. But please don't post your whole code instead.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, but in MainActivity its no returning null, I called Log.i("TAG",grid_columns);
and its Logs TAG 3

Comment: Everything is working fine, the only problem is the NullPointerException in  AdapterListView.
How it works:
The user can set the number of items per line in the MainActivity GridView in a PrefecenceActivity, and its stored in a SharedPrefences File.
All the time the app starts it reload the gridview layout, to check the value of the itemsperline.
Before it loads, it checks the SharedPreferences and the String containing the value is stored in a String and transfered to another class.

Comment: In MainAcivity I dont get any errors, but in AdapterListView when I get the string and use it somewhere else I get a NullPointerException

Comment: I dont see you saving    grid_columns anywhere in that class you linked to.  show me where you are saving it

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but how do I save it in my class?
I did in that way:
MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
        String grid_columnsA = main.grid_columns;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onCreate()` is not called when you make a new instance of an Activity. If you need to pass data from an activity to another activity, you can store the data inside an intent with a key, and retrieve that value with the key.

If you really need to access some variables in a different way other than using intents, you can send a reference of the Activity as a parameter, and read the public fields or call a getter method.

Most important is that `onCreate()` is not a constructor, and is part of the Activity lifecycle that is only called in runtime when the activity is started, not when it is initiated.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.grid_columns = sp.getString("grid_columns", "3");
}
```

You are initiating the string on the `onCreate()` method. That is why

```
    MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
    String grid_columnsA = main.grid_columns;
```

is returning a null pointer exception, because creating a new instance of the `MainActivity` will NOT call `onCreate()`.

What you CAN do is send the String as a parameter when creating the `AdapterListView` and pass the string in the public constructor,

Or set a `setGridColumns(String s)` method in AdapterListView,

```
mylist.setAdapter(new AdapterListView(MainActivity.this, names, mImageLoader));
```

and instead of doing this, save a reference of the `AdapterListView` that is being created in this line, call the setter method, and then call the `setAdapater()` method.

Final method you can choose is that you are passing down the activity as a `Context` object in the constructor of the `AdapterListView`. Cast this into a `MainActivity` and access `grid_columns` within the constructor. Although this is not safe because the `Context` may not always be `MainActivity`, if this is the only case you are using this object, it will work fine.

Comment: Man you are the best!! Your answer totally solved my problem and now changind the layout depending to the variable is working like a charm. In the future I hope I will have this knowedge and solve others people problems like you. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

this was wrong

```
//getting the String from the other activity
    MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
    String grid_columnsA = main.grid_columns;

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);
        Log.i("TAG",grid_columnsA);
//NullPointerException in this line (Log.i...)
```

it should be

```
//getting the String from the other activity
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String grid_columnsA = prefs.getString("grid_columns", "3");

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);
        Log.i("TAG",grid_columnsA);
//NullPointerException in this line (Log.i...)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the problem its not in SharedPreferences, I log the String in MainActivity and no erros, BUT, when transfering the variable to the other class, the variables returns null.
Maybe Android is deleting it from memory?

Comment: I believe Shared Prefs is stored to disk you should double check making sure that you are opening the same file that has the same name.  Also make sure you are saving it before loading it.

Comment: Yes, I already checkd in raw file, but even if the file its not there, it shoud take 3 as the default value.

Comment: I see what you did check my change